# Open / load image as numpy ndarray directly

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I used to use scipy which would load an image from file straight into an ndarray.

```
from scipy import misc
img = misc.imread('./myimage.jpg')
type(img)
>>> numpy.ndarray
```

But now it gives me a `DeprecationWarning` and the [docs say it will be removed in 1.2.0.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) and I should use imageio.imread instead. But:

```
import imageio
img = imageio.imread('./myimage.jpg')
type(img)
>>> imageio.core.util.Image
```

I could convert it by doing

```
img = numpy.array(img)
```

But this seems hacky. Is there any way to load an image straight into a numpy array as I was doing before with scipy's `misc.imread` (other than using OpenCV)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result of `imageio.imread` is already a NumPy array; `imageio.core.util.Image` is an ndarray subclass that exists primarily so the array can have a `meta` attribute holding image metadata.

If you want an object of type exactly `numpy.ndarray`, you can use `asarray`:

```
array = numpy.asarray(img)
```

Unlike `numpy.array(img)`, this will not copy `img`'s data.

Comment: Suppose you do this and you end up with two images in that array. How do you get the ith item of that array, meaning a specific image (e.g. the second)?

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan: The docs say `imread` reads *an* image, so I don't know how you could end up with two.

Comment: Ah yes! Of course! I have this piece of code `for level in args.levels.split(","):
        if level == 'm': 
            img = fimage.associated_images["macro"]
        else:
            level = int(level)
            img = fimage.read_region((0, 0), level, fimage.level_dimensions[level])
        img = np.asarray(img)[:,:, 0:3]` but I was totally not realising the for-loop. So for each item it will produce an image and put it in an array. Weirdly enough you helped me a lot @user2357112-supports-monica!

Answer (score 0):

If it was a bitmap or even jpeg, you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# 'pip install pillow' but import PIL
from PIL import Image

png_filepath = 'somepng.png'
png_pil_img = Image.open(png_filepath)
# this will print info about the PIL object
print(png_pil_img.format, png_pil_img.size, png_pil_img.mode)
png_np_img = np.asarray(png_pil_img)
plt.imshow(png_np_img) # this will graphit in a jupyter notebook
# or if its grayscale plt.imshow(png_np_img, cmap='gray')
# FWIW, this will show the np characteritics
print("shape is ", png_np_img.shape)
print("dtype is ", png_np_img.dtype)
print("ndim is ", png_np_img.ndim)
print("itemsize is ", png_np_img.itemsize) # size in bytes of each array element
print("nbytes is ", png_np_img.nbytes) # size in bytes of each array element
```

If you have a jpg, it works the same. PIL.image will decode the compressed JPG, and convert it to an array for you.  Literally it will do all [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) for you.  Perhaps you could load the raw [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) with file io skipping the header, yadda yadda, but PIL is popular for a reason.

The output for a grayscale png will look like this:

```
PNG (3024, 4032) L
shape is  (4032, 3024)
dtype is  uint8
ndim is  2
itemsize is  1
nbytes is  12192768
```

The output for a color jpeg will look like this:

```
JPEG (704, 480) RGB
shape is  (480, 704, 3)
dtype is  uint8
ndim is  3
itemsize is  1
nbytes is  1013760
```

In either case, the pixel values range 0-255 as ints.  They are not floats.  The color image has three channels corresponding to red green and blue.  The grayscale image is much greater resolution and the jpg.